# how to run .sh file in python and pass input to it?

Tags: linux

I have some bash scripts and I need to run them.
in bash scripts, there is some os command that needs inputs.
I need a way to send input to this bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just open sh(test.sh) file and in it write this way:

```
bash 2_extract_image_from_data_src.sh <<< "

png
"
```

an enter and png send as input to this sh
then just run test.sh in terminal("bash test.sh")